# How to customize nticks in persp R

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I am new to R 3D plotting. I basically have a matrix of size 9x3. Here is what I have to plot them:

```
###loads the above matrix
d2 <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T, dec=".",sep = " ")
###loads x,y,z
x <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(3,4,10)
z <- as.matrix(d2)


persp(x, y, z,
  zlab="Score", ylab = "C", xlab="T",
  theta=40, phi=-5, ylim=c(3,10), xlim=c(2,10), 
  nticks = 5, ticktype = "detailed",  
  col="springgreen", shade=0.5)
```

Everything is fine except that I am not happy with the ticks on the axes.

Is there a way to force the nticks for `x`, and `y`, and `z`?

For example, is there a way to do something like `x.nticks=5` , `y.nticks=2`, `z.nticks=7`?

**Edit**: dput(d2) output:

```
structure(list(X571.4711426 = c(415.0601344, 398.2104115, 392.3533142, 
389.1941271, 388.099164, 387.919963, 387.8443483, 387.808006, 
387.8046256), X569.3318221 = c(412.6845238, 396.1001583, 390.6924488, 
387.7928128, 386.7903531, 386.6250436, 386.549898, 386.5178556, 
386.5147072), X564.8071975 = c(408.1278631, 392.3859494, 387.5985228, 
384.9989269, 384.0664302, 383.9174889, 383.8442499, 383.8178535, 
383.8151726)), .Names = c("X571.4711426", "X569.3318221", "X564.8071975"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: could you use `dput`?

Comment: @Hack-R can you provide an example? Not familiar with dput

Comment: @user3639557  you type `dput(d2)` and copy / paste the output to StackOverflow so that we can read in your table

Comment: @user3639557 Thanks, makes it much easier to try to help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
d2 <- structure(list(X571.4711426 = c(415.0601344, 398.2104115, 392.3533142, 
                                      389.1941271, 388.099164, 387.919963, 387.8443483, 387.808006, 
                                      387.8046256), X569.3318221 = c(412.6845238, 396.1001583, 390.6924488, 
                                      387.7928128, 386.7903531, 386.6250436, 386.549898, 386.5178556, 
                                      386.5147072), X564.8071975 = c(408.1278631, 392.3859494, 387.5985228, 
                                                                    384.9989269, 384.0664302, 383.9174889, 383.8442499, 383.8178535, 
                                                                    383.8151726)), .Names = c("X571.4711426", "X569.3318221", "X564.8071975"
                                                                    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
d2

x <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(3,4,10)
z <- as.matrix(d2)

pmat <- persp(x, y, z,
              zlab="Score", ylab = "C", xlab="T",
              theta=40, phi=-5, ylim=c(3,10), xlim=c(2,10), 
              col="springgreen", shade=0.5ticks
)

min.x  <- min(x)
max.x  <- max(x)
x.axis <- seq(min.x,max.x,by=2) # by = 2 will get you 5 ticks
min.y  <- min(y)
max.y  <- max(y)
y.axis <- seq(min.y,max.y, by = 5) # by = 5 will get you 2 ticks
min.z  <- round(min(z))
max.z  <- round(max(z))
z.axis <- seq(min.z, max.z, by=5) # by = 5 will get you 7 ticks 

tick.start <- trans3d(x.axis, min.y, min.z, pmat)
tick.end   <- trans3d(x.axis, (min.y - 0.20), min.z, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)

#Note the (min.y - 0.20) in the calculation of tick.end. This places the second line, parallel to the X axis, at the position -0.20 on the Y axis (i.e., into negative/unplotted space).

#The tick marks on the Y and Z axes can be handled similarly:

tick.start <- trans3d(max.x, y.axis, min.z, pmat)
tick.end   <- trans3d(max.x + 0.20, y.axis, min.z, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)

tick.start <- trans3d(min.x, min.y, z.axis, pmat)
tick.end <- trans3d(min.x, (min.y - 0.20), z.axis, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)

labels <- as.character(x.axis)
label.pos <- trans3d(x.axis, (min.y - 0.25), min.z, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(0, NA), srt=270, cex=0.5)

#The adj=c(0, NA) expression is used to left-justify the labels, the srt=270 expression is used to rotate the labels 270°, and the cex=0.5 expression is used to scale the label text to 75% of its original size.

#The labels on the Y and Z axes are produced similarly:
labels <- as.character(y.axis)
label.pos <- trans3d((max.x + 0.25), y.axis, min.z, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(0, NA), cex=0.5)

labels <- as.character(z.axis)
label.pos <- trans3d(min.x, (min.y - 0.5), z.axis, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(1, NA), cex=0.5)

# And you can of course change the specific settings to whatever you want
```

**Fully Custom Ticks Example**
[image: custom]

Comment: Very nice and thanks - is there a way to put back the axes labels zlab="Score", ylab = "C", xlab="T"?

Comment: @user3639557 Thanks, glad to help. Sure we can add those back, just give me 1 min.

Comment: @user3639557  I was able to get those to show up by removing the `axes = F` option. That also adds the arrows indicating the direction of the scale of the axes. If you want to get rid of those, you could probably play with the options some more, but hopefully they make it better if anything. This link will help with further customization: http://entrenchant.blogspot.co.id/2014/03/custom-tick-labels-in-r-perspective.html  Feel free to mark this as the solution if you find it helpful :)

Comment: @user3639557 One final note -- when I want to really, *really* tweak a plot like this a lot, such as for publication, I sometimes find it helpful to export it as a vector image and open it in an image editor like GIMP or Photoshop. Not that you need it for this, but just in case you want to take it to the next level.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful - I think you accidentally deleted the beginning of your code :)

Comment: @user3639557 Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I just updated it. Glad to help!